# querySelectorAll loop "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

I try to loop over few input elements in order to get each value, but for some reason I only get the last one:

```
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<button type="button" onclick="loop()">loop</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    function loop() {
        var element = document.querySelectorAll('[data-loop="true"]');
        for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            console.log(element[i].length);
            // or:
            // document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = element[i].value + '<br>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

The console shows `undefined` and when I try to output the values, I only get it from the last element and not from all of them. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much (and please excuse my english)

Comment: there is no length attribute on the DOM element the number of elements is element.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get the `length` of the element itself:

```
console.log(element[i].length);
```

Elements don't have a length.

I suspect you are trying to get the length **of the value** of the elements:

```
console.log(element[i].value.length);
```

```js
function loop() {
  
        // elements will be a "node list" containing any/all elements
        // that match the query.
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-loop="true"]');
      
        // Because it is a node list, which is an array-like object,
        // it has a "length" property:
        console.log("There were " + elements.length + " elements found.");
      
        // ...And, it can be looped through
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            // It's contained elements are indexed and when you do that,
            // you may access properties of the elements themselves
            console.log(elements[i].value);
            // or:
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += elements[i].value + '<br>';
        }
    }
```

```html
<p>Type some text in the textboxes and then click the button:</p>
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" />
<button type="button" onclick="loop()">loop</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: No, I try to get the number of elements (with `element[i].length`) to see if its working, and it shows `undefined`

Comment: Then you want: `console.log(element)` and you don't need a loop.

Comment: So how can I get all of the values (from each element, I mean: `element[i].value`)?

Comment: @natanel97 Look at my example code, which does just that.

Comment: It's awesome! but how can I make a limit for one click only?

Comment: @natanel97 What do you mean? The user can only click the button once?

Comment: Ignore the "but how can I make a limit for one click only?", I solved this. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try to `console.log(element[i])`; This is because here `element` will be a collection of DOM  elements.

There is no length property for these elements.

Since they are `input` and if you want to get their `value` you need to log

```
element[i].value
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
console.log(element[i].length);
```

`element[i]` refers to an [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).  It and non of its parent classes have a `length` property.  Assuming you want to display the length of the value of the input element, the following would work.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function loop() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('[data-loop="true"]');
  element.forEach( (e) => {
    output.innerHTML += `${e.value}: ${e.value.length}<br>`;
  });
}


function clearOutput(){
  output.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" value="one" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" value="two" />
<input type="text" name="input-loop" data-loop="true" value="three" />

<button type="button" onclick="loop()">loop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearOutput()">clear</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach. From MDN: "Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate on it using forEach().  **Several older browsers have not implemented this method yet.**"  Those same browsers will have trouble with your arrow function and your templated strings as well. Just FYI.